# Disable click on a asp control texbox from an external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp textbox control,which is set as a timepicker using Jquery.I need to disable click on a timepicker.What i have tried is

```
 $('#texbox1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

But this is disabling the field but some time is not updated properly.

Also tried using Css

```
  pointer-events: none;
```

But not working on IE.

Also tried using

```
       $('#textbox1').prop("readonly", true);
```

but timepicker is not being disabled.

Comment: Set the TextBox1.ClientIDMode="Static" and then try with the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $('#textbox1').timepicker().on('click',function(e){$('.bootstrap-timepicker-widget').css('display','none')})
```

or you can try with your text box only

```
   $('#textbox1').on('click',function(){$('.bootstrap-timepicker-widget').css('display','none')})
```